# Do Until Loop does not stop when condition is met

Tags: vba, excel

I Hvae the following code:

```
Public Sub CiscoPrimeReport111()
    Dim rowCounter As Long
    Dim colCounter As Long
    Dim throughputAP As Long


    throughputAP = 2
    rowCounter = 8
    colCounter = 1

    MsgBox ("Please do the following before pressing the OK BUtton on this Popup Window!!:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "1. Open the CISCO PRIME AP Report you want to use" & vbNewLine & _
        "2. Select all the data (Ctrl + A)" & vbNewLine & _
        "3. Copy ALL the content (Ctrl + C)" & vbNewLine & _
        "4. NOW YOU CAN PRESS THE OK BUTTON!")


    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Call createCiscoSheet


    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cisco Raw")
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(rowCounter)
            Do Until Cells(rowCounter, colCounter).Value = "AP Statistics Summary"
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Throughput Per AP").Rows(throughputAP).Resize(1, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = _
                .Rows(throughputAP).Value '.Resize(1, .Columns.Count - 1).Value
                throughputAP = throughputAP + 1
                rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
            Loop
        End With


    End With
End Sub
```

the code runs well and the'Do Until' loop runs well too but it is not stoping when the following condition is met:

```
Do Until Cells(rowCounter, colCounter).Value = "AP Statistics Summary"
```

it just keeps on looping until the end of the source sheet.

any ideas why? i am a noob at this so any help is appreciate it!

Comment: My first guess is that you have not specified the sheet it should be checking.

Comment: Is "AP Statistics Summary" always going to be in column 1?  Because you never change your `colCounter`.

Comment: @Comintern, hi mate, yes, it will always be in col 1

Comment: Cells(rowCounter, colCounter).Value = "AP Statistics Summary" may not be checking where you think it's checking. Better to fully qualify your references...

Comment: change `With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(rowCounter)` to `With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` and put `.` in front of `Cells(...` in the next line: `Do Until .Cells(rowCounter, colCounter).Value = "AP Statistics Summary"`

Comment: When carrying out this sort of check, you need to be certain that the cell contents **exactly** match your search string, including case and whitespace. If you are not certain of this, it is a good idea to use `Trim()` to remove surrounding whitespace and either `LCase()` or `UCase()` to make the casing the same in the comparison.

Comment: As an alternative; why not use a Range.Find function to get the row then use a 'for N = 8 To LastRow' loop instead? It will be easier to debug if the correct row is being returned from the initial Find function.